# the meaning of '\' using in #define

Tags: c++, char

I want to know the meaning of the code "\". I have seen some explanation before, but I forget, who can tell me?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

ofstream out("order.out");

#define CLASS(ID) class ID {\
public: \
   ID(int) { out<<#ID " constructor\n;} \
   ~ID() { out<< #ID "destructor\n";}\
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes the compiler see the current line and the line after `\` as the same line.

For defines this is important, as the preprocessor only takes into account what's on the current line.

For example:

```
#define CLASS(ID) class ID {
public: 
   ID(int) { out<<#ID " constructor\n;} 
   ~ID() { out<< #ID "destructor\n";}
};

CLASS(foo)
```

would expand to

```
class foo {
```

whereas

```
#define CLASS(ID) class ID {\
public: \
   ID(int) { out<<#ID " constructor\n;} \
   ~ID() { out<< #ID "destructor\n";}\
};

CLASS(foo)
```

would expand to

```
class foo {
public: 
   foo(int) { out<<"foo" " constructor\n;} 
   ~foo() { out<<"foo" "destructor\n";}
};
```

Answer (score 6):

The backslash (`\`) at the end of each line means that the next line is a continuation of the current line.

So

```
#define class(ID) class ID
```

Is identical to

```
 #define class(ID) class \
 ID
```

Comment: One additional thing to be aware of is that this line continuation isn't just for `#define` - it's pretty much on any line.  In most cases this doesn't really matter in C/C++ except for macro definitions (unless you like breaking lines in the middle of an identifier). But one place it can occur (and cause a nasty surprise) is if you have one at the end of a `//` style single line comment - in that case the next physical line is considered part of the comment.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of `'\'` in `#define`.

`\` allows you to write multiline macros. `\` is appended at end of each line.

You can have more inforamtion on http://www.cs.cornell.edu/andru/mlm/syntax.html

Answer (score 1):

Its a backslash. Its mostly used when a line of code is too big and needs to be split into pieces for readability and documentation. it concatenates one line to the next and can be chained for multiple lines too.

Answer (score 1):

It allows you to have a multi-line #define by concatenating lines that end with a backslash, with the next line.